# What is the rate limit on github commits api

Tags: github, commit, github-api

I need to know the rate limit of using the api from:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/

for one of my university projects. However, it doesn't seem to be explicitly mentioned on their website.

Or is it part of the search API? or events?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about limits imposed by an off-site vendor or service and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For unauthenticated requests, the rate limit allows for up to 60 requests per hour and for API requests using Basic Authentication or OAuth, you can make up to 5000 requests per hour.

https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting